# MassTransit v6 UseSendFilter

Tags: dependency-injection, middleware, masstransit

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //other configuration
    services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>(); //register dependency
    services.AddScoped(typeof(MySendFilter<>)); //register generic filter
      
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
          cfg.UseSendFilter(typeof(MySendFilter<>), context); //generic filter
        });
    });
}
```

https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html#usage

I am trying to execute the code above. I created a .net-core 3.1 app and installed MassTransit, MassTransit.AspNetCore, MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection, and MassTransit.RabbitMQ (v6.3.2). However, neither UseSendFilter nor UsingRabbitMq methods could be found.

Comment: You need MassTransit v7 to use generic filters.

Comment: In V6 is there any solution for a scoped pipeline? I need a consumer middleware which holds dependencies as scoped.

Comment: I don't think so, it was added in v7.

Comment: Do filter and consumer belong to the same scope? In my case, I have IntegrationEventPublisher class which holds list of events. In the consumer's consume method I add some event objects to the list. However, I cannot see any items in the list when I check IntegrationEventPublisher in the filter after `await next.Send(context);` line.

Comment: They should be in the same scope, yes. The scope should be created at the first point in the pipeline where a scope is required, which in your case might be the filter. There is a video on middleware that covers how previous scopes were created on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/Y4Z5puk4jW4).

Comment: I could not place filter and consumer classes in the same scope. I will create a seperate question for this. Thanks for your response for the versioning.